# Tuleap: Exiting with error Insufficient group access - why?

Tags: permissions, tuleap

I recently installed Tuleap on a CentOS 6 VM instance. I created a couple of test projects, in prep for demoing Tuleap to my IT group. After deleting a project I'd created, called Administrative Project, I am now unable to browse to the admin page as the admin user. The error I receive is:

Insufficient group access
You do not have permission to view this page

The Tuleap logs don't show anything of use. Has anyone else encountered this issue? How to fix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted the wrong project. Could you connect to the mysql database (credentials can be found in /root/.tuleap_passwd , go to the tuleap database and issue a:

```
select group_name, status from groups where group_id=1;
```

Could you print back the result here.

UPDATE

So, as it appear you deleted the wrong project, the administration project of Tuleap which is responsible for determining who is an admin and who is not and thereby preventing you to be recognised as an admin anymore. To reactivate it try to issue a:

```
UPDATE groups SET status='A' WHERE group_id=1;
```

Tell me if it solved your problem.

Regards, Martin

Comment: Hi Martin - Here's the query

mysql> select group_name, status from groups where group_id=1;
>+------------------------+--------+
>| group_name             | status |
>+------------------------+--------+
>| Administration Project | D      |
>+------------------------+--------+
>1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Apologies for the formatting...

Comment: Okay, so it confirms that you simply deleted the wrong project, the administration project of Tuleap which determined who is administrators an so on. I will update my answer.